# Find the probability of success in Logistics Regression using R

Tags: r, classification, probability, logistic-regression

I am running logistic regressions using R in a data set.
Below is the sample code:

```
classifier=glm(formula = Output~.,family =  inomial,data=df_train,maxit = 100)
prob_pred=predict(classifier,type = 'response',newdata = df_tes[-5])
y_pred = ifelse(prob_pred>0.4,1,0)
```

Here `Output`is my target variable. It is a binomial classification problem.
`Success` and `Fail`are two factors.

But here i want my o/p as Probability of `Success`. Means in each record i want to find the Probability(of Success) value.(Ex: 68%,45%,36% etc.)

I am new to R programming, could anyone please help me.

If this question has already been asked anywhere, kindly provide me the link.

Comment: Have you looked inside the `prob_pred` object? That should be it. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164648/output-of-logistic-regression-prediction

Comment: Will `predict(classifier, type="response")` work for you?